Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' while running the test cases
I was getting the "cannot import statement outside of a module" error while running the test cases which I resolved by writing in the package.json file
"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "./node_modules/(?!(MY_LIBRARY|@stencil)/)"
    ]
  },

but when this issue is resolved, now I am getting the another error regarding the Unexpected token <,
attaching the screenshots what error I am getting, and what is the file structure for that package in node_modules

I tried everything, like installing the jest-transform-stub, make the mocks of svg but didn't work out anything, also giving the code which I am using for jest configuration
jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
    },
  
    // Test spec file resolution pattern
    // Matches parent folder `__tests__` and filename
    // should contain `test` or `spec`.
    testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
  
    // Module file extensions for importing
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"]
  };


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Hey Sanjana S: please stop defacing the question. I have edited it to remove the problematic content.

Voting to close as this appears to contain proprietary code and has not been reduced to a minimum verifiable example.

Since it looks like you're trying to import an .svg file, jest needs to know how to handle such imports since they're not js files.
Try adding a transform for .svg files?
You can use jest-transformer-svg by installing it:
npm install --save-dev jest-transformer-svg

And then adding it to your jest.config.js:
transform: {
  "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
  "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-transformer-svg",
}

